# Android Vertical Seek bar

Tags: java, android, progress, seekbar, touch-event

I am creating a custom vertical seek bar. I have the following problem with the vertical seek bar: When I move my vertical seek bar and my thumb moves out of the seek bar then the seek bar's `onStop()` method does not get called.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: no need to create vertical seekbar just apply `android:rotation="90"` to horizontal seekbar.

Comment: thanks for fast reply but not a proper solution...thank u very much..

Comment: @Ketan any other solution .?

Comment: onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) is the method called whenever touch response is recognized. 

MotionEvent.ACTION_UP is the constant for recognized finished touch gesture

Comment: @MandarKakade : Thanks for your reply. But when i put my thumb out of seek bar while moving seekbar Action_up is also not calling.

Comment: @MandarKakade: I am also suffering from the same problem.Give other option if u have.

Comment: thanks all i solve this problem put on stop method in Action_Cancel.

Comment: @KushalShah try this solution ..thanks